# Проблема с SQL запросом?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть 2 таблицы: companies, tizers. Таблица companies связана c таблицей  tizers через атрибут id - id_company(1 компании принадлежит несколько тизеров). 
Необходимо с помощью AR или DBQuery написать запрос, который выберет все тизеры, принадлежащие включенным компаниям (is_show = 1) c id 5,6,7

Структуры таблиц ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следующий запрос не работает

```
$tizers = (new \yii\db\Query())
->select(["(tizers.`count_clicks` / tizers.`count_show`) * tizers.`multiplier` AS ctr",'tizers.`title`,tizers.`id`,tizers.`img`,companies.`link`,companies.`is_show`,tizers.`id_company`'])
->from('tizers')
->innerJoin('companies', 'tizers.id_company = companies.id')
->where(['companies.`is_show`' => 1])
->andWhere(['in','tizers.`id_company`',$idsCompanies])
->orderBy([
    'ctr' => SORT_DESC,
])
->all();
```

Comment: в каком смысле не работает? не выполняется вообще, или выводит не тот результат что вы ожидаете?

Comment: выводит не тот результат что я ожидаю

Comment: Выполните **getRawSql()** и приложите получившийся код

Comment: А про таблицу `news` Вы нам зачем рассказали? она тут вообще не нужна... удалите лишнее из вопроса.

Comment: Как выполнить getRawSql() ? Т.е как написать?

Comment: #@ОлегБас

(new \yii\db\Query())
->select(["(tizers.`count_clicks` / tizers.`count_show`) * tizers.`multiplier` AS ctr",'tizers.`title`,tizers.`id`,tizers.`img`,companies.`link`,companies.`is_show`,tizers.`id_company`'])
->from('tizers')
->innerJoin('companies', 'tizers.id_company = companies.id')
->where(['companies.`is_show`' => 1])
->andWhere(['in','tizers.`id_company`',$idsCompanies])
->orderBy([
 'ctr' => SORT_DESC,
])->createCommand()->getRawSql();